# Confusion about the first and the last elements of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am confused about whether we add elements to the front of a linked list or the back. Let's assume that we have a linked list that goes like: `x->a->c->v`; here, is `x` the first or the last element? Secondly, what should I do if I want to add `x->a->c->v->h` or `h->x->a->c->v`? This confused me when I encountered the following question:

> Consider implementing a circular singly linked list data structure. Suppose the pointer `ptr` of the circular linked list points at the last node whose `link` fields points atht eh first node of the linked list. Complete the algorithms for `add(...)` and `delete(...)` specified below. You can write in pseudo code or C code. Assume the following declarations for linked list node structure:
>
> ```
> typedef struct list_node* list_pointer;
> typedef struct list_node {
>      int value;
>      list_pointer link;
> }
>
> list_pointer ptr = NULL;
> ```
>
> Note that if the circular linked list is empty, its pointer `ptr` would be set to `NULL`.
>
> ```
> // Add node at the front of the circular list ptr; ptr points at the last node in the list
> void add(list_pointer *ptr, list_pointer node) { ... }
>
> // Delete the front node from the list ptr
> list_node delete(list_pointer *ptr) { ... }
> ```

Comment: to make things simpler, think of forward list

Comment: @codekaizer can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common terms used for linked lists are `head` and `tail`.

In a non-circular list, like the ones you show in your question, the `head` node would be the node that no other node in the list points to, so you need another pointer, a `listHead` pointer, to point to it.  Since you generally traverse the list starting with the node that `listHead` points to, the `head` node can also be thought of as the `first` node in the list.

In a non-circular list, the `tail` node is the node that does not point to any other nodes.  It can be thought of as the `last` node in the list.

Now, in a circular list, like the one referenced in the text you linked, the definition  of `head` and `tail`, and of `first` and `last` can be a little more complicated, since every node points to another node and has another node pointing to it.  Where a circular list starts and ends is usually determined by the sorting order of the list, if there is one, or some other traversal criteria that controls what order you go through the list in.

A basic circular list could include a `listHead` pointer that points to the `first` node that you should visit when going through the list.

Some more advanced circular lists will change to using a `listTail` pointer, pointing to the last node of the list.  This is done because, with a circular list, it is easy to get to the `head` node if you have a pointer to the `tail` node, since the `tail` node will point to the `head` node.  So by providing a pointer to the `tail` node, you get quick access to both the `last` and `first` node in a list.  This is the type of data structure your linked text was describing.

Now for your questions about inserting, that is really up to you and how you want to use the list.  If the list is unordered, it is much faster to insert a new node as the new `head` of the list.  But if you want to implement a First-in, First-out list, then perhaps you want to insert new nodes as the new `tail` of the list.  And of course, if there is an order to your list, based upon some data each node contains, then you want to find the correct position in your list to insert a new node in order to preserve the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

The first element is `x`, since that's the first element you would get to if you traversed the list by following the chain of `next` pointers.

When adding to a linked list you can either add before the first element or after the last element. Adding before the first element is more efficient, because you don't have to follow the entire chain of `next` pointers to find the end.

Answer (score 1):

You choose the direction of your own list. Usually by naming the pointers to the previous and next nodes previous and next. How you name them determines the order. If you have a doubly linked list, your node has both pointers.

Nevertheless you always store pointers to both the first and last element. That way you can have `push_front`, `pop_front`, `push_back`, `pop_back` functions.

However, if you have a forward list, (you only store the `next` pointers in your node, then you can't have a `pop_back`, because your last node has no link to the previous node, and you don't know what the new last element becomes.

So a

- forward list can have: `push_front`, `pop_front`, `push_back`,
- a backward list can have: `push_front`, `push_back`, `pop_back`,
- and a doubly linked list: `push_front`, `pop_front`, `push_back`, `pop_back`,